# Native Select Menu in HTML/CSS/JavaScript for Windows 8.1 Store Apps filling entire viewport width on Surface Pro

Tags: select, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1, windows-rt

I have a Surface Pro running an HTMl/CSS/JavaScript Store App on Win8.1. There's a standard HTML select menu like this:

```
<select>
    <option>Option</option>
</select>
```

When you tap it the select menu expands to the full width of the viewport. This is reproducible within the Visual Studio/Blend Simulator at the 1920x1080 140% scaling resolution.

Any ideas as to why this is happening and how it could be resolved?

Here's the simulator at 10.6" 1920x1080 @140%

[image]

Here's the simulator at 23" 1920x1080 @100% (app is blanked out)

[image]

Thank you

Comment: it's up to the browser on how to render form fields such as `input`, and `select`.

Comment: It's the same browser rendering them differently (IE11) based on device scaling.